# Weird issue with orber by, inner join in wordpress query

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am working on a custom plugin in wordpress. I have a weird issue with one sql.

SQL:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts. *
FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships 
ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id )
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy 
ON ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id )
WHERE 1 =1
AND wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
AND wp_term_taxonomy.term_id IN ('23')
AND (
wp_posts.post_author =1
)
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
AND (
wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private'
)
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
ORDER BY `wp_posts`.`as_stats_rating` DESC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

---

Its returning the correct data but its not sorting results according to as_stats_rating. 
I am stumped. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

### **Edit 1 : Update**

Here is the structure of wp_posts:
[image]

---

Sample result:

```
ID  as_stats_rating
1221   8
1222   10
```

All fields in sample results are :
ID  post_author     post_date   post_date_gmt   post_content    post_title  post_excerpt    post_status     comment_status  ping_status     post_password   post_name   to_ping     pinged  post_modified   post_modified_gmt   post_content_filtered   post_parent     guid    menu_order  post_type   post_mime_type  comment_count   as_stats_numviews   as_stats_numvotes   as_stats_votestotal     as_stats_rating

---

By the way, its not only about 'order by wp_posts.as_stats_rating', 'order by wp_posts.as_stats_numviews' have the same issue. (just to clear up, if you are wondering about as_stats_rating having varchar type)

Comment: i would suspect a conflict with the limit statement.  as a check, take the limit off and see if the order by is correct.

Comment: @Randy : No. Just checked by removing limit clause, the issue persist.

Comment: It already has a group by, what should be the group by?

Comment: Is wp_post.ID an auto_increment?

Comment: What does a sample result set look like?

Comment: Is the column `as_stats_rating` definitely part of the `wp_posts` table? And if so, shouldn't the clause be `\`wp_posts.as_stats_rating\` DESC`?

Comment: @methodin : added sample results above

Comment: @TheDeadMedic : Yes as_stats_rating is definitely part of wp_posts table. Added the structure of wp_posts in the question. Also `wp_posts.as_stats_rating` gives mysql error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any chance that the `as_stats_rating` field is a string (char/text) datatype and not a numeric (float/int/decimal) datatype?

Comment: Hell. I am so sorry about this questions. As it turns out changing datatype to int solved the issue. Coming to think of it, it was sorting 8 > 10 as texts.